# How to override preceding html tags bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have a code like this.

```
<style>
    #container ul li{ font-size:50px;}
    .myclass1 ul li{ font-size: 20px;}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="myclass1">
                <ul>
                    <li>Something 1</li>
                    <li>Something 3</li>
                    <li>Something 3</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="myclass2">
                    <li>Something 1</li>
                    <li>Something 3</li>
                    <li>Something 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this example what I want is the block that has **myclass2** could be a class which can inherit or copy **li** style properties of default **twitter bootstrap's ul and li value**

Basically **myclass2 = twitter bootstraps default li styles.**

Because when I want to use bootstraps default styles for myclass2, I have to reset it and do a lot of coding.

I just want to inherit bootstrap's default ul,li behaviors to myclass2 or overriding preceding tags, without writing tons of code over and over again.

I think this is a must for twitter bootstrap.

**ADDITION :** 
Real life example. Please check http://www.carantina.com/

Under **'PRODUCTS'** the style of li and ul tags are coming from inherit ones. But I want to use default bootstrap values. How I will achieve that. 
[image]

Comment: If you've loaded the bootstrap CSS, its default values for `ul` and `li` **will** get applied to your `ul` and `li` elements, by default. What makes you think you have to do something to make that happen? A concrete example of the "tons of code" you have to do "over and over again" would improve the question markedly. Right now it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Crowder`s statement is valid ,i dont get why you have to code (as per you) for using default css styles that comes from twitter bootstrap

Comment: Please check this code. For myclass2 if I want to use default bootstrap values, I have to revert back everything by hardcoding. I cannot just type <code>font-size:defautbootstrap'sfontsize</code> The example above is very simple. Just think it for a dropdown menu.

Comment: I edited my reply. There is a real life example. Just tell me how I can use twitter bootstraps default values for that tabbed bar.

Comment: Then use corresponding class of style you want to apply, no?!

Comment: @roasted as you can see in this dropdown menu, if I use li style inside li, it is trying to use preceding li styles. So I have to get all bootstrap default values and create a class for that which is a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webpage is structured differently than your example here, but the question for the example here could be solved by writing

```
#container ul ul:not(.myclass2) li {font-size:50px;}
#container .myclass1 ul:not(.myclass2) li {font-size: 20px;}
```

for the CSS. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/jXKkt/).
Then the top list with `myclass1` will be 20px, and the bottom list with `myclass2` will be the system default (on a Bootstrap webpage, it would be the Bootstrap default).

However, since there are only two lists, and two styles in effect, there will be nothing displayed at 50px. So either your example doesn't fit, or I misunderstand your requirements.